# How save OpenCvSharp.Mat with CV_8UC1 type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, opencv

I wrote the following code to load a picture with any type,
I convert it to type CV_8UC1 and then save it again in the file.

The problem is that when I load the saved image it is not a CV_8UC1 type but a CV_8UC3 type.

Where am I wrong?

```
    private void SaveTest()
    {
        var fileName = @"F:\src.png";
        Mat src = new Mat(fileName);
        var gray = src.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
        Debug.Assert(gray.Type() == MatType.CV_8UC1);

        var fileName2 = @"F:\temp.png";
        gray.ImWrite(fileName2);
        Mat test = new Mat(fileName2);
        Debug.Assert(test.Type() == MatType.CV_8UC1);
    }
```

Comment: images are loaded by default as `CV_8UC3` (i.e. `IMREAD_COLOR`). You should use `IMREAD_UNCHANGED`. Not really sure how to do this in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change instead this:

```
Mat test = new Mat(fileName2);
```

this:

```
Mat test = new Mat(fileName2, ImreadModes.Unchanged);
```